# Vuex -- mapState in parent and pass as prop, or mapState directly in child?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

If I'm loading a large object in App.vue and committing it to the store at init, is it better to do the mapStating in a parent component and pass the object to the a child (where it will be iterated / used / displayed) or is it better to mapState the object directly in the child where it is being used?

Followup... does either make a difference in availability of someBigArray? I find I always have to deep watch mapStated objects and assign them to local data() variables on change which feels like such a hack.

`// state.someBigArray`

```
// ---------------------------------------> parent 

<template>
  <Child :the-object="someBigArray"/>
</template>
computed: mapState(["someBigArray"]),

// ---------------------------------------> child 

<template>
  <div v-for="item in someBigArray">
     {{ item.name }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
props: {
  locations: {
    type: Array,
    required: true,
    default: () => [],
  },
}
```

Comment: Either can work, so you need to define "better". Maintainability I suppose? What is in bigArray? What do children do with it? If as shown, only display it, I would prefer props because I see children more easily reusable then, but ofc ymmv and as always, better in terms of what.

Comment: On the other hand, if I'm always working with the same bigArray, and have different ways or parts to display, I can also see using the opposite approach. E.g. I doubt your `v-for="item in someBigArray"` example is the total of that component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get data from Vuex where you want to, depending on your specific case. But if your child component is a UI component that is not supposed to do any calculations, I'd better passed all data with props, no matter how big it is.

Also you can avoid such hack by making a getter for your data and using `mapGetters` in `computed` section of your component. And I find using mapState a bit not secure, so I prefer using mapGetters instead.

#### Update

Actually Vuex docs [encourages use of mapState](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html), so it seems that getters are unnecessary if you don't need to modify data in some way.